# Change port speed by SNMP (Switch D-link/Cisco)

Tags: snmp, cisco

How to change Bandwidth port limit by SNMP?
 There are OID for check Bandwidth port traffic, but I can't find any MIB to change the port limit.

Answer (score 0):

Changing port attributes can't be done directly through SNMP.  You would need to have a system to create a file including all the configuration changes you want applied and then use SNMP to copy the file to the device and apply it.

Comment: Do you have a place where I could find more information on how to do this?

Comment: The first google result is http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_configuration_example09186a0080094aa6.shtml.